# importing R. (android)

Tags: android, import, r.java-file

I have searched through Stack Overflow as I know this is a common question, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. This included cleaning my project, deleting all imports and deleting the project and starting again entirely.

I am using the Eclipse specifically for android on mac (ADT bundle mac).

Whenever I create a new project I have errors immediatley in my src folder on the line
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

and also on inflate.

Any suggestions other than those stated? It is literally before I have done any programming so cannot understand what is wrong.

EDIT: Fixed. Downloaded the SDK a second time and this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Make sure you didn't mistakenly deleted the gen folder from the source folders. If you didn't and you did import everything properly, the only reason R.java won't exist is that you have a layout / style / Strings / Manifest error causing it not to build properly

Comment: i guess you have an error in your res folder preventing the R file to be generated

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: This might also happen if you accidentally replace the package declaration at the top (e.g. by cutting and pasting code). In any case, one should never have to import R explicitly (`import com.example.myapp.R`).

Answer (score 7):

import The R class. The basic syntax is

```
import your_application_package_name.R;
```

If you have already imported it but it is not working then check if there in any error in your resource xmls. If so then r can be not generated and that error will be shown

Comment: Thank you, but 1) I have tried this and it doesn't work.
2) From what I have read, I shouldn't have to import r

Comment: Unless it's in a different package

Comment: But seeing as I have just opened android, it should be all set up to code right? I haven't moved anything and R should be in the default location.

Comment: What is the reason to import the R class?! Sorry I am new to android.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Project Build Target to the Latest

Right Click Project > Properties > Android > Change the Api to latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the Android_SDK. When you create or import a new Android project the SDk builds  the project. The R problem is mostly an update SDK problem.

Comment: I downloaded this http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE so it should be as up to date as possible.

Comment: try to update the SDK Android and EclipseIDE, from eclipse, or maybe some eclipse plugin... have a look in eclipse preferences