# Cannot resolve symbol 'R'. (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Already did gradle rebuilding, syncing and cleaning of the project. Still it does not work. My Android studio version is 2.2.

Comment: Go to file, click on **Invalidate cache and Restart**

Comment: sync gradle file in gradle scripts

Comment: this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900473/1868008

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's no error in one of your resource files?

Comment: @nobalG already tried that, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1) Invalidate cache and restart.
2) Check out your resource files ( in your case, check layout file )
3) Place your cursor over "R" and import the suitable one for you.